# UITableViewController - image background

Tags: ios, swift, image, uitableview, background

i have UITableViewController, and I'm trying to set a image background.
the issue is the background image does not fit the whole screen, in other words, the image background **does not** stretch with the table cells.
this my code

```
    let imgView =  UIImageView(frame: self.tableView.frame)
    let img = UIImage(named: "b2")
    imgView.image = img
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.width, self.tableView.frame.height)
    imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
    self.tableView.addSubview(imgView)
    self.tableView.sendSubviewToBack(imgView)
```

[image]

Comment: Does table view fit whole screen? Whats height of your table view?

Comment: i have not change the tableView size, so it's as default. i tried to add this line, but it's still does not stretch to the whole view.          self.tableView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

Comment: don't you use autolayout

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try with this code:

```
 tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "640x1136.png"))
```

[image]

Add this code in `ViewDidLoad`